# How to get correct gmt time in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, mechanicalturk

For using the Amazon mechanical turk API I want to get the current GMT time and show it in ISO format

```
2011-02-24T20:38:34Z
```

I am wondering if there is any way to correctly get the gmt time and also be able to reformat it with ISO format. I can use something like `now.toGMTString();` but it makes a string out of the date and it is hard to reformat it with ISO.

Comment: Check the documentation for methods on the [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/global_objects/date)

Comment: This is outside the scope of your question, but you're probably better off getting this value server-side.  You can use the setUTC...() functions if you need a javascript Date object based on the server-provided time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function pad(num) {
    return ("0" + num).slice(-2);
}

function formatDate(d) {
    return [d.getUTCFullYear(), 
            pad(d.getUTCMonth() + 1), 
            pad(d.getUTCDate())].join("-") + "T" + 
           [pad(d.getUTCHours()), 
            pad(d.getUTCMinutes()), 
            pad(d.getUTCSeconds())].join(":") + "Z";
}

formatDate(new Date());
```

Output:

```
"2011-02-24T21:01:55Z"
```

Comment: Lucky there is now [*toISOString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.toisostring). ;-)

Answer (score 4):

```
var year = now.getUTCFullYear()
var month = now.getUTCMonth()
var day= now.getUTCDay()
var hour= now.getUTCHours()
var mins= now.getUTCMinutes()
var secs= now.getUTCSeconds()

var dateString = year + "-" + month + "-" + day + "T" + hour + ":" + mins + ":" + secs + "Z"
```

You should be using UTC now instead of GMT. (Amounts to almost the same thing now, and it is the new standard anyway)

Comment: It's not bad, aside from the fact that it doesn't pad 1 digit numbers, and doesn't account for the fact that months will be 0-11 instead if 1-12

Comment: Those are pretty big errors. It also prints the day of the week where the day of the month should be.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the only problem here is that the output is not iso compatible I had to add 01 instead of 1. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

I believe this will work for you:

```
Number.prototype.pad = function(width,chr){
    chr = chr || '0';
    var result = this;
    for (var a = 0; a < width; a++)
        result = chr + result;
    return result.slice(-width);
}
Date.prototype.toISOString = function(){
    return this.getUTCFullYear().pad(4) + '-'
        + this.getUTCMonth().pad(2) + '-'
        + this.getUTCDay().pad(2) + 'T'
        + this.getUTCHours().pad(2) + ':'
        + this.getUTCMinutes().pad(2) + ':'
        + this.getUTCSeconds().pad(2) + 'Z';
}
```

Usage:

```
var d = new Date;
alert('ISO Format: '+d.toISOString());
```

*Not much more different than every else's answer, but make it built-in to the date object for convenience*

Comment: getTimezoneOffset() is in minutes, so you might need to use addMinutes rather than just subtracting the offset.

Comment: @Dave: True, still playing with it, so not finished tweaking. ;-) But good call.

Answer (score 2):

This script can take care of it

```
/* use a function for the exact format desired... */
function ISODateString(d){
function pad(n){return n<10 ? '0'+n : n}
return d.getUTCFullYear()+'-'
  + pad(d.getUTCMonth()+1)+'-'
  + pad(d.getUTCDate())+'T'
  + pad(d.getUTCHours())+':'
  + pad(d.getUTCMinutes())+':'
  + pad(d.getUTCSeconds())+'Z'}
var d = new Date();
document.write(ISODateString(d)); // prints something like 2009-09-28T19:03:12Z
```